# Блокировать повторный вызов alert javascript

Tags: javascript, alert

Есть ли способ блокировать повторный вызов алертов при перезагрузке страницы??

Answer (score 2):

Можно записать в [cookie](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie) или [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) флаг о том, что алерт уже был вызван:

```
if(!localStorage.alertCalled) {
   alert('Alert');
   localStorage.alertCalled = true;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо )) Попробую ))